# How to copy Cert to remote server

Tags: powershell, certificate

How do I copy cert to remote without getting the following error:

`Copy-Item : Source and destination path did not resolve to the same provider.`

Here's my code:

```
$CertsCheck = Get-ChildItem -Path $origpath -D -recurse | Where-Object { $_.name -eq "Certs" } 

$PublicCert = "CERT:\LocalMachine\TrustedPeople"
$PrivateCert = "CERT:\LocalMachine\My"

if  (!$CertsCheck) { Write-Host "Certs directory doesn't exist in $origpath." }

else {
    $CertsDirectory = Get-ChildItem -Path $OctopusOriginalPackageDirectoryPath | foreach-object -process { $_.FullName } | Select-String -Pattern "Certs"
    $PublicCertExistTest = $PublicCert + "\$file"
    $PrivateCertExistTest = $PrivateCert + "\$file"

    foreach ( $file in Get-ChildItem -Path $CertsDirectory -Recurse )
    {
        $PrivateCertExistTest = $PrivateCert + "\$file"
        if (( $file -like "*.pfx") -and (-Not (Test-Path $PrivateCertExistTest )))  {
            Copy-Item $file.FullName $PrivateCert
            Write-Host "$file was copied" to $Privatecert

    }
        $PublicCertExistTest = $PublicCert + "\$file" 
        if (( $file -like "*.cer*" ) -and (-Not (Test-Path $PublicCertExistTest )))  {
            Copy-Item $file.FullName $PublicCert
            Write-Host "$file was copied" to $PublicCert
    }
}
```

Comment: I changed my code to "certutil -addstore -f  "LocalMachine\My" $File.FullName".  This is now giving me this exception.    CERT:\LocalMachine\My 
Info 17:13:10
Cannot open Cert store. CertUtil: -addstore command FAILED: 0x80070035 (WIN32: 53) CertUtil: The network path was not found.                        Can someone help.  I haven't been able to find solution to this.

Answer (score 0):

You could use PowerShell's [Import-Certificate](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh848630(v=wps.630).aspx) cmdlet.